# How to prove that $\ln f(t)-\ln f(0)\le t?$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(t), f'(t)>0$ for every $t\in [0,T]$. Moreover,
$$f'(t)\le f(t)\quad\text{for every $t\in [0,T]$}.\qquad (1)$$
$f$ is increasing. 
How to prove, that under the above hypothesis
$$\ln f(t)-\ln f(0)\le t?\quad(2)$$
Naturally, (2) imples (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f'(t)\le f(t)\implies \dfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\le 1\implies \int_0^t\dfrac{f'(s)}{f(s)}ds\le\int_0^t1ds\implies \ln f (t)-\ln f(0)\le t,$$ where we have used that $f>0.$